# react-bootstrap : validation not working on a second form

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-bootstrap

I have two components each one rendering a form formatted and validated by react-bootstrap. The validation code and layout of the first form works perfect but not the second one. The form doesn't fire any feedback whatever is my validation case...

Im I doing something wrong ?

Here is the second form :

```
<Form noValidate validated={this.state.validated} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <Form.Group controlId="testForm">
       <Form.Control placeholder="test" required/>
       <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
         Please provide a value.
       </Form.Control.Feedback>
    </Form.Group>
 <input className="col mt-4 btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Envoyer" />
</Form>
```

Comment: `noValidate` attribute means it won't validate your form...

Comment: noValidate is for cancel the browser default validation UI. https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/?#forms-validation. I'm I not supposed to get help ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the handleSubmit() method. I used to have this :

```
handleSubmit(event){
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }else{
    this.setState({validated:true});
    event.preventDefault(); 
   }
}
```

instead of this :

```
handleSubmit(event){
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }else{
   ...
   }
    this.setState({validated:true});
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

I also had to create one file for each form...

Hope this helps somebody.